# Querying a table for a list then use that list in a select statement

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Lets say I have a table that holds a list of other tables

```
Declare @MyList varchar(max)
@MyList = Select tablename from ListofTables
```

it brings back a list of 50 tablenames

How can I use that list of tablenames in a single select statement? I was thinking a for loop or something maybe?

```
For each tablename in @MyList
Select * from tablename
```

Comment: Your first version should not work as you expect if `ListofTables` has more than one table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try with the next approach:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #ListOfTables (
   [TableName] varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #ListOfTables
   ([TableName])
VALUES
   ('Table1'),
   ('Table2'),
   ('Table3'),
   ('Table4'),
   ('Table5'),
   ('Table6'),
   ('Table7'),
   ('Table8'),
   ('Table9')

-- Statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N''

SELECT @stm = @stm + N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME([TableName]) + N'; '
FROM #ListOfTables
/* 
-- Or using FOR XML PATH
SELECT @stm = (
   SELECT CONCAT(N'SELECT * FROM ', QUOTENAME([TableName]), N'; ')
   FROM #ListOfTables
   FOR XML PATH('')
)    
*/

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Comment: This is approach I would use, also could use table variables instead of temp table. Also would be cognizant of databases and schemas, either use that in the query or better yet in the table of tables names.